# Displaying JSON Data from API in Django

Tags: javascript, python, css, json, django

I am looking for a simple way to display JSON values coming from an API in a Django project. I've got everything working to read the JSON data into an object and store as variables, etc. but I am  wondering how to make a dynamic way to display the values from the JSON Object.

Say for example the JSON looks like this

```
{
   "status":"OK",
   "copyright":"Copyright (c) 2017 Pro Publica Inc. All Rights Reserved.",
   "results":[
      {
         "num_results": 10,
         "offset": 0,
         "bills": [
              {
                 "bill_id": "hr2739-113",
                 "bill_type": "hr",
                 "number": "H.R.2739",
                 "bill_uri": "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/113/bills/hr2739.json",
                 "title": "Efficient Use of Government Spectrum Act of 2013",
                 "sponsor_title": "Rep.",
                 "sponsor_id": "M001163",
                 "sponsor_name": "Doris Matsui",
                 "sponsor_state": "CA",
                 "sponsor_party": "D",
                 "sponsor_uri": "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/M001163.json",
                 "gpo_pdf_uri": "http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/BILLS-113hr2739ih/pdf/BILLS-113hr2739ih.pdf",
                 "congressdotgov_url": "https://www.congress.gov/bill/113th-congress/house-bill/2739",
                 "govtrack_url": "https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/113/hr2739",
                 "introduced_date": "2013-07-18",
                 "committees": "House Armed Services Committee",
                 "committee_codes": ["HSAS","HSIF"],
                 "subcommittee_codes": ["HSAS26","HSIF16"],
                 "primary_subject": "Science, Technology, Communications",
                 "summary_short": "Efficient Use of Government Spectrum Act of 2013 - Directs the Federal Communications Commission (FCC), within three years after enactment of the Middle Class Tax Relief and Job Creation Act of 2012, to: (1) reallocate electromagnetic spectrum between the frequencies from 1755 to 1780 megahertz (currently, such frequencies are occupied by the Department of Defense [DOD] and other federal agencies); and (2) as part of the competitive bidding auctions required by such Act, grant new initial lic...",
                 "latest_major_action_date": "2013-08-29",
                 "latest_major_action": "Referred to the Subcommittee on Intelligence, Emerging Threats &amp; Capabilities."
              },
                           {
                 "bill_id": "hr3355-113",
                 "bill_type": "hr",
                 "number": "H.R.3355",
                 "bill_uri": "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/113/bills/hr3355.json",
                 "title": "Reducing Employer Burdens, Unleashing Innovation, and Labor Development Act of 2013",
                 "sponsor_title": "Rep.",
                 "sponsor_id": "G000558",
                 "sponsor_name": "Brett Guthrie",
                 "sponsor_state": "KY",
                 "sponsor_party": "R",
                 "sponsor_uri": "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/G000558.json",
                 "gpo_pdf_uri": "http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/BILLS-113hr3355ih/pdf/BILLS-113hr3355ih.pdf",
                 "congressdotgov_url": "https://www.congress.gov/bill/113th-congress/house-bill/3355",
                 "govtrack_url": "https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/113/hr3355",
                 "introduced_date": "2013-10-28",
                 "committees": "House Armed Services Committee",
                 "primary_subject": "Economics and Public Finance",
                 "summary_short": "Reducing Employer Burdens, Unleashing Innovation, and Labor Development Act of 2013 - Expresses the sense of Congress that increasing the competitiveness of U.S. manufacturers will strengthen the national economy. Title I: Investing in America&#39;s Workforce - Investing in America&#39;s Workforce Act - Amends the Workforce Investment Act of 1998 to require state or local workforce investment systems to use youth activities funds allocated to a local area for programs that provide training, which may...",
                 "latest_major_action_date": "2014-01-24",
                 "latest_major_action": "Referred to the Subcommittee on Intelligence, Emerging Threats &amp; Capabilities."
              },
```

I would want this to return in HTML 2 different entries. But for example, if this API call was to return 5 entries, I would want it to return in HTML 5 different entries. What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop on the JSON object and, for example, create table rows to disply the results. Like if you JSON object name is "result". You can loop over the "bills" using jquery something like below. I have just added first 4 elements. you can add as many depending on your Json object. Finally "trHTML" can be added to HTML page as table. Loop would iterate on any number of bills, like 4, 5, 100 dynamically

```
$.each(data['bills'] , function (index, item) {
          trHTML += '<tbody><tr><td>'+item[0]+'</td><td>'+item[1]+'</td><td>'+item[2]+
          '</td><td>'+item[3]+'</td></tr></tbody>';

        });
```